# how to write into "build problems" tab in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I´m trying to integrate googletest with my Qt Creator.

Basically I´ve got a googletest-listener, which evaluates my unit tests and prints the results to stdout. Now I´m trying to make that listener a build step, so it tells me when a test didn´t succeed. The results are now shown in the "Compile Output" tab.

What I want to do now is that the results are shown in the "Build Problems" tab as well. Just like normal build errors. Is this somehow possible without using a Creator-plugin?

EDIT:
In the meantime I´ve found the solution: It seems like Qt Creator takes all the "build problems" from stderr instead of stdout. So I just wrote my errors to stderr and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

No, the build output is specifically made to catch compile and link errors, which Qt Creator links to the relevant parts of the source code when you click on the items in this list. Compile output is the full output of things like `[n]make` or `msbuild` build tools. Custom build steps only show here, with a plugin, you could of course do all kinds of magic (I have no experience here, but as everything in Qt Creator is a plugin, it should be very possible).

Comment: actually it is possible by just writing to stderr instead of stdout. It was so easy I didn´t even think about it, just found out by accident. So it may not be how it´s meant to be done, but it works.